# Массовое переименование файлов rename

Tags: linux, shell

Как с помощью утилиты `rename` переименовать все файлы, оставив первые 8 символов и расширение?

К примеру, имеем:

```
001-superfile-blaha_bla.txt
```

Необходимо:

`001-supe.txt`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

предуведомление: под «расширением», как я понимаю, подразумевался суффикс файла, начинающийся с символа `.`

---

если в качестве программы `rename` испольуется `prename` (*perl*-овая реализация, чаще встречается именно она), то можно переименовать так:

```
$ prename 's/^(.{8}).*(\.[^.]+)$/$1$2/' *
```

---

кстати, если этой программе передать опцию `-n`, то реального переименования не произойдёт. это может быть полезно для тестов:

```
$ prename -n 's/^(.{8}).*(\.[^.]+)$/$1$2/' *
001-superfile-blaha_bla.txt renamed as 001-supe.txt
```

Comment: Всем спасибо. Помогло! Использовал perl-rename

Answer (score 2):

Можно и без rename:

```
for i in *.txt ; do mv -v $i ${i::8}.txt; done
```