# Пробелы в nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть файловый сервер на Win. Под него подняли nginx на Centos. Наименование некоторых папок содержат пробел в конце наименование. Например 21_06\plan\plan \1.jpg. 
Как удалить пробел в конце папки используя регулярные выражения, так, чтобы файл открывался.

Comment: Приведите больше информации для ответа. Где и на чем планируется применять регулярные выражения?

Comment: Переименовать файлы и каталоги не вариант?

Comment: `21_06\plan\plan \1.jpg` — ничего себе имечко вы выбрали для файла! у вас проблемы только с пробелом, или с тремя обратными слэшами в имени файла проблемы всё-таки тоже есть?

Comment: ну а вообще [prename](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451339/178576) вам в помощь