# Как поменять названия файлов с помощью команды find в определенной папке сервера

Tags: shell, find

Есть на сервере много файлов с названиями примерно "fakeshop.css?version=23423423" "templantes.css?main=23423423" и т. д.

подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать во всех названиях файлах все, что идет после ".css"

Вот нашел код на просторах интернета только что то он не хочет менять названия файлов

find /var/www/www-root/data/www/domen.ru/ -type d -name "*.css?*" -exec rename 's/(\w+).css.*$/$1.css/' *  \;

Comment: файлы имеют разные названия, единственное что у них одинаково это ".css?"

Comment: протокол ssh здесь вообще никаким боком. ну а ввиду того, что не знаете, какая оболочка используется, пусть будет общая метка для posix-совместимых оболочек — `shell`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Массовое переименование файлов rename](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451330/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-rename)

Comment: да shell но вы в дубликате указали ссылку на вопрос который мне не решает проблему

Comment: вот нашел код `find /var/www/www-root/data/www/domen.ru/ -type d -name ".css?*" -exec rename 's/(\w+)\.css.*$/$1\.css/' * \;`  он правильно составлен?

Comment: 1. понимаю, что **на самом деле** вам нужно регулярное выражение, покрывающее «всё после "css"». но вопрос-то ваш совершенно о другом. 2. а вы проверьте. как это сделать, написано по приведённой ссылке. проверять, естественно, надо «на кроликах», а не «на сервере».

Comment: мне нужна не только регулярка а полностью работающая команда.

Comment: про то, что вы привели, можно вполне определённо сказать что «оно» — «полностью работающее». за исключением, возможно, регулярного выражения — его, конечно, надо проверить.

Comment: нет оно что то не хочет работать, в место регулярки использовал простые замены